# YCSB - Difference between recordcount, operationcount and insertcount parametres

Tags: benchmarking, ycsb

Please, what is the difference between recordcount, operationcount and insertcount parametres.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this github issue](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/issues/1206):

> - recordcount: how many records YCSB assumes are present or will be present in the backing data store
> - operationcount: how many workload operations YCSB should perform (scan / read / whatever according to the % breakdown in the workload)
> - insertcount: how many records a particular YCSB client ought to insert during a load phase.

Comment: If operation count is 0 what does it mean?

Comment: @developthou data will be loaded but there would not be any operations like read or update.